# Select column based on cell

Tags: r

I have a df like so:

```
color=c('red','red','blue')
red = c(10,30,50)
blue = c(123,456,789)
df = data.frame(color,red,blue)
```

FOr each row, I would like to select the column value according to which colname is equal to the value in the color column

eg:

```
color2=c('red','red','blue')
answer=c(10,30,789) 
df2=data.frame(color2, answer)
```

I have tried:
test=match(df$color, names(df))
test2 = df[,test]

but this gives me:

```
red=c(10,30,30)
red.1=c(10,30,30)
blue=c(123,456,789)

wrong = data.frame(red,red.1,blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use row index along with the column index from `match` to extract the values

```
cbind(df[1], answer = df[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
                       match(df$color, names(df)[-1]) )])
#    color answer
#1   red     10
#2   red     30
#3  blue    789
```